# How to overload a function taking variable number of arguments

Tags: c++, overloading, variadic-functions

I need to distinguish (overload) between two functions - one takes a single `const char*` argument and the other takes at least two arguments - a `const char*` followed by one or more arguments.
i.e. basically:

```
void f(const char *str);
void f(const char *format, ...)
```

I want the first version to be called for `f("hello")` and the second version for `f("hello %d", 10)`. The above overload won't work because the compiler finds `f("hello")` ambiguous.

So I tried this:

```
void f(const char *str);

template<typename T>
void f(const char *str, T tt, ...);
```

This makes the overload resolution work correctly. But I end up with another problem. The second function is supposed to forward the arguments for printf-style usage. So I have something like:

```
template <typename T>
void f ( const char *format, T tt, ... )
{
    (T)tt;
    va_list varlist;
    va_start(varlist, format);
    vprintf(format, varlist);
    va_end(varlist);
}
```

Now the second argument `tt` is no longer part of the variable argument list and calling `va_start()` with `format` [does not seem to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24824965/second-argument-of-va-start).

Is there any way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Do not reinvent the wheel, just use `fmt` library, which largely is part of C++20.

Comment: @MarekR Unfortunately, I am limited to a c++17 compiler.

Comment: AFAIK [fmt](https://fmt.dev/latest/index.html) supports C++11, it was just partially included into new standard. I'm using that extensively with C++17 on all desktop platforms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use a vararg template you can accomplish what you want:

```
#include <iostream>

void f(const char* str)
{
    std::cout << "single arg: " << str << "\n";
}

template <typename ...T>
void f(const char *format, T... args)
{
    printf(format, args...);
}

int main()
{
    f("hello");
    f("formatted %d", 10);
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the perfect solution. But I wonder how this works. Doesn't vararg template also mean 'zero or more'?, i.e., without the first overload, the second one matches both the function calls (with one argument and two). So how is the situation different from my first example? Does the template instantiation have a lower priority for overload resolution?

Comment: The templated function has lower priority than the non templated function. The main difference is that it's c++ rather than c, the c varargs arguments aren't part of the function signature, note that the compiler doesn't complain that your functions are ambiguous when calling them but complains that you've declared functions with incompatible signatures

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using templates is not the best idea, since the second error seems more difficult to fix than the first. The overload of the functions is fine, it is more if you try in a separate file you will see that it works.

```
#include <iostream>

bool f(const char* str) {
    return true;
}

bool f(const char* str,int n) {
    return false;
}

int main(int argc,char* argv[]) {
    std::cout << f("Hi") << std::endl;       //Gives 1
    std::cout << f("Hi",10) << std::endl;    //Gives 0

    return 0;
}
```

You could also try creating a namespace and putting the functions in there, thus making sure that no other files share that function name that can cause that error.

Comment: your `f` is not variadic, so its just natural that the error caused by `...` refering to zero paramters is not present in your code.

Answer (score 0):

- Q: why compile error?
- A: becauz scope of "void f(const char *format, ...)" had cover "void f(const char *str);".

so the cute solution is you should better using arg num to distinguish 2 func.
like this:

```
void func_with_one_arg(const char *str) {
     printf("func_with_one_arg");
}

void f(int arg_num, const char *format, ...) {
    if (arg_num==1) return func_with_one_arg(format);
    printf("func_with_multi_arg\n");
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, format);
    va_end(ap);
}
```

if you want to automately coumpute variable arg_num, use this macro to help computing.

```
#define VA_LENGTH_(_0, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, _11, _12, _13, _14, _15, _16, _17, _18, _19, _20, N, ...) N
#define VA_LENGTH(...) VA_LENGTH_(0, ## __VA_ARGS__, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0)
#define ExecVF(Func, ...) Func(VA_LENGTH(__VA_ARGS__), __VA_ARGS__)
```

now you should use ExecVF like this:

```
int
main(int argc, char **argv) {
        ExecVF(f, "foo", "bar");
        ExecVF(f, "foo");
        return 0;
}
```